# Wallet Adapter Saga Mobile

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, phantom-wallet, walletadapter, mobile-wallet-adapter

I cannot get the Anza/Solana Wallet Adapter to work with Saga mobile with any wallets.

When I try to sign a Message or Tx I get "Wallet Error: Unexpected Error".

The provided demo does not work with my Saga either: https://anza-xyz.github.io/wallet-adapter/example/